# What is is the origin of "Pupengang"? When was it referenced first?

Tags: etymology

When I was growing up, in the Berlin-area, 80s and 90s, I learned the word "Pupengang" as a synonym of "Angst", especially before giving talks/presentation or before visiting the dentist. One could say it is related to "Lampenfieber" for more generic situations.

A quick Google-search revealed no origin or first references or usages, could someone help me out there? I'm looking for its "inventor".

I'd not be surprised if someone like Goethe is the original author. I can clearly picture why the word exists, as my stomach works hard, just before the mentioned events. It's this kind of words which makes German a funny language for me.

Comment: Not knowing anything about it, I would, as a first guess, relate it to *pupen* i.e. *pupsen*, i.e. farting, and read farting as a polite placeholder for stronger acts of backside expression, which may occur as bodily reactions to strong fear, see also *die Hosen voll haben*, or *to be scared shitless* in English. I have however no idea who used the word first possibly in print (so that we would know about it).

Comment: I guess this is a typical berlin-style word creation, but it might get difficult to find a written reference ...

Comment: @Arsak I more have the feeling that it comes from "north".

Comment: @PatrickB. *pupen* is definitely Berlin-Brandenburg-style.

Comment: I'm living in Berlin for 51 years now but never heard the expression "Pupengang".

Comment: Maybe the eastern part of Berlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Pupe** is a word that was (and maybe still is?) used in the eastern part of Berlin and also in Brandenburg and means *After* (engl. anus) based on the verb [pupen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pupen) meaning *to fart*.

The phrase

> jemandem geht die [Muffe](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Muffe)

meaning *sb. is frightened* is also phrased

> jemandem geht die Pupe

and therefore the word for *being frightened* (Muffengang) is

> Pupengang.

[Der wahre E: ein Wörterbuch der DDR-Soldatensprache von Klaus-Peter Möller](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=2pVArWDoHEAC&lpg=PA174&ots=6SQnI4GQwJ&dq=Angst%20Pupengang&hl=de&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q&f=false) lists *Pupe* and *Pupengang* on page 163.

[image]

The example phrase

> Du kannst mich mal an der ~ schmatzen.

might be the reason why Goethe comes to your mind in that regard. In the 3. act of his 1773 puplished play [Götz von Berlichingen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6tz_von_Berlichingen_(Goethe)) he lets him say:

> Er aber, sag's ihm, er kann mich im Arsche lecken!

meaning *But he, tell him, he can lick me in the ass.*.

This is widely known as the *Götz-Zitat* (Götz quote).

[image: Götz-Zitat]
<sup>[source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Goetz_von_Berlichingen_in_Weisenheim_am_Sand.jpg/384px-Goetz_von_Berlichingen_in_Weisenheim_am_Sand.jpg)</sup>

There is also a canon composed by Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart called [Leck mich im Arsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leck_mich_im_Arsch).

Neither Goethe nor Mozart are the original authors of the phrase that wikipedia calls [Schwäbischer Gruß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schw%C3%A4bischer_Gru%C3%9F).

---

<sup>[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pupe) also lists *Pupe* as *Homosexueller; berlinerisch auch für verdorbenes Weißbier* but that has nothing to do with the meaning you are looking for.</sup>

Comment: Das Substantiv "Pups" und das Verb "pupsen" sind sicher mit "Pupe" verwandt und sind allgemein bekannt. Vgl. auch https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pupsen